# Unable to access newly added column in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have added migration for add new column like this:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.addColumn('Topics','isFeatured',{
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false
    })
    done()
  },
  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.removeColumn('Topics', 'isFeatured')
    done()
  }
}
```

then run migration as

```
sequelize -m
```

its add new column with default value.
But when I retrieve this api

```
updateTopic = function (req, res) {
  db.Topic.find(req.params.id).success(function (topic) {
    console.log(topic.isFeatured)
    // some code
  });
};
```

then I got `console.log(topic.isFeatured)` is undefined

but `console.log(topic)` show topic with default false value of isFeatured.

So anybody can help me to find out why `console.log(topic.isFeatured)` is undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have not added `isFeatured` column in your model definitions, you have to add it to your model definitions.

```
module.exports = function (db, DataTypes) {
  var Topic = sequelize.define('Topic', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    // other columns
    isFeatured: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  });
  return Topic;
}
```